# Error Cannot resolve symbol ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, push-notification

I have been trying to set up push notifications in my android studio but im getting this error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ParsePushBroadcastReceiver' Validates resource
>   references inside Android XML files.

in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file

On the parse website it says that the device has been registered though but  When I send the notification I never get a notification but it says on the website that it went through.

I have checked my settings and Notifications are allowed for my app.

Answer (score 0):

May be the jar files which you are using are not updated ones.Please use this link https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing